# Sort posts by custom field - numbers and string

Tags: wordpress, sorting, wordpress-theming

So i have a custom field that gives output as plain text in this format: dd. MM yy (09. October 2013). This is the loop that im using:

```
query_posts(array('category_name'=>'somecategory', 'posts_per_page'=>'5','paged' => get_query_var('paged')));
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

//stuff
the_field('mydate'); //the output is: dd. MM yy
//stuff

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
//paginate_links code...
```

If i add this to query_posts:

```
'meta_key' => 'mydate', 'orderby'=>'mydate'
```

My posts get sorted only by day and year couse it seems it cant read the month couse its a string. And this kind of sorting is kinda usless. If the site was my i would change date format and it would be solved, but i am doing this site for someone and the designer already draw this date format in photoshop so it has to be this way. So how can i make this sort work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code before you query_posts:

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_orderby');
 function filter_orderby( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= "  AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'mydate' ORDER BY mydate DESC";
    return where;
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: thx for replying. when i add this code before query posts it makes all the posts dissapear. i also have 2 more loops on my page that have diferent category and are not related to this one, and they also dissapear. i tryed with and without this: ('meta_key' => 'mydate', 'orderby'=>'mydate') but its the same result. do you know what could be cousing this?

Comment: pl try this one :query_posts(array('category_name'=>'test', 'posts_per_page'=>'5','paged' => get_query_var('paged'),'order'=>'ASC' ,'orderby'=>'meta_value' ,'meta_key'=>'mydate'));

if not works, please let me know your date format

Comment: Still dosent work, it sorts only by day. my custom field date format is: dd. MM yy (09. October 2013). @Bhum if its only numerical it works, but my date is not all numerical as you can see

Comment: Yes but you can pass numeric value at the time to store and change format when you want to display.

Comment: Ok, could you tell me how or give me a link? I wouldnt be here asking people for help if i knew how to do it

Comment: You can store date with format YYYY-mm-dd and change format when you displaying with <?php echo date("m. F Y",$your_date_variable); ?>

Comment: I changed storing format and i displayed it like u said. I did this: $your_date_variable=the_field('mydate'); and then i called it like you said. But it displayed 01. January 1990 and that was not the correct date i put in. What did i do wrong?

Comment: could you pl apply strtotime <?php echo date("m. F Y", strtotime($your_date_variable)); ?>